# How to perform the operation in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table called items_per_order. I want to perform the following operation:
(1 * 500) + (2 * 1000) + (3 * 800) + (4 * 1000).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can perform operations using standard maths operators:

```
SELECT *, item_count * order_occurrences AS total FROM your_table;

item  order  total
1     500    500
2     1000   2000
3     800    2400
4     1000   4000
```

And you can calculate the total using the `SUM` function:

```
SELECT SUM(item_count * order_occurrences) AS total FROM your_table;

total
8900
```

Comment: Now if I were to perform the arithmetic mean would it work? Like this:
SELECT ROUND(SUM(item_count * order_occurrences)/SUM(order_occurrenes),1) as mean
FROM table;

Comment: The above should work just fine.